# ASP.NET Core 2 : Ajax calls to API with [Authorize] fail the preflight request

Tags: c#, cors, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an API controller with the `[Authorize]` attribute to ensure all calls are made by properly logged-in users (via OpenIdConnect, targeting Azure AD) . When I load the page that makes the Ajax calls, the API responds properly.

However, after a certain amount of time, the user has to be reauthorized, and thus a call to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/` is made by the ASP.NET Core framework to reauth the user. That calls fails with the following error:

> Failed to load https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?[truncated]: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://my.website.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I tried to configure the CORS header with this code, but that doesn't solve  my issue:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // allow reconnection on API calls
    app.UseCors(builder => builder
        //.WithOrigins("https://login.microsoftonline.com")
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials()
    );

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Note that ASP.NET Core version 1.0 didn't have that issue (though ASP.NET MVC 5 did).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specifics here, but did implement a CORS based SSO once: The target of the CORS request (`login.microsoftonline.com` in this case) needs to allow your origin -> can/did you enter your site as allowed on the Azure AD side?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `login.microsoftonline.com` doesn't include CORS headers, and I don't think that will change..

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround to my problem.

I didn't solve the preflight request CORS issue. `login.microsoftonline.com` doesn't include CORS headers, so I'm not even sure it can be solved.
However, I found a way to increase the cookie timeout, to decrease the need to re-auth the user.

When using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`, there are several cookies:

- the `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme` cookie
- the `IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme` cookie
- the `IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme` cookie
- the `IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme` cookie

The one used for AJAX requests is the `IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme` cookie, which by default is set to expire after 5 minutes (you can see the defaults on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L45)).

To increase the external cookie timeout:

```
services.ConfigureExternalCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14);
});
```